# Join fields in excel using powershell

Tags: csv, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

```
(1..$numrows) | ForEach-Object {
   $sheet.Cells.Item($_,1) = -join $sheet.Cells.Item($numrows,1) + '-1234';
}
```

I am trying to join the `-1234` in a row of a csv file
My result is `System.__ComObject-1234`

Could you please advise about the error message?

Answer (score 0):

1 - You cannot start an expression with a switch, `-join` is not a command. Example use : `$myJoinedArray = $array -join ";"`

2 - You don't need `-join`, `+` is enough to concatenate strings.

3 - I think you want `$sheet.Cells.Item($numrows,1).Value` :

```
(1..$numrows) | ForEach-Object {
   $sheet.Cells.Item($_,1) = $sheet.Cells.Item($numrows,1).Value + '-1234';
}
```